# Facebook review build must work on Xcode 7.3 simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook

Facebook has rejected a simulator build created with Xcode 9.4.1, targeting iOS 11+, that was submitted for review with the message:

> Please ensure that the Simulator Build provided works with Xcode Version 7.3, as this is the software our team uses in review. More information about creating simulator builds can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced#sim_build).

Is it possible to create such a build with Xcode 9? 
I have tried installing the build I submitted on the Xcode 7.3.1 simulator like this:

```
DEVELOPER_DIR=/path/to/Xcode-7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer\
&&\
xcrun simctl install booted \
/Path/to/Xcode/DerivedData/App-Identifier/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/App.app
```

but when I try to launch the app it crashes immediately, leaving an `assertion failed:` message with some hex digits in the system log. I suspect this is because it does not support iOS 9.3, which the simulator is running, but there could have been other changes to the simulator that are causing it to fail.

The link facebook provided says to run in the Xcode iPhone 5 simulator, but my version of Xcode only seems to have simulators going back to the 5s.

Do I need to make my app run under iOS 9.3? Or re-write it in swift 2.2 so I can build it using xcode 7.3?

Comment: Hi @Thomas Adams, 
Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: I believe it turned out to be a generic error message from them, I can’t remember what the actual problem was, but I think it was something particular to our app, maybe it was crashing on launch or our login flow was broken in the simulator.